# What's the name of this type of tree?

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

What's the name of a tree that looks like the below?

I've provided a few iterations $d = 0,1, \dotsc$, because it looks sort of fractal. The `0`'s are nodes, and the lines, edges.

$d=0$

```
0
```

$d=1$

```
  0  
  |  
0-0-0
  |  
  0
```

$d = 2$

```
       0
       |
  0  0-0-0  0  
  |    |    |  
0-0----0----0-0
  |    |    |  
  0  0-0-0  0   
       |
       0
```

I was thinking of calling them "lattice trees", but after a bit of Googling, it looks like these might be called "star-like" trees, but if anyone could give a reference or a confirmation that would be nice.

The way I've constructed them is by setting the length of the maximum path in the graph to be $2d$ and then tried to have as many vertices as possible.

Comment: If you order the tree from the nodes of $d$ up-down, setting the center node at the top, what is doing is just adding three new nodes from each node of the previous level (except for $d=0$ where the tree add four new nodes).

Comment: If we were to consider the center vertex as the root, if it weren't for the fact that it had four children, I would have called it a full, complete and balanced ternary tree, or a perfect ternary tree.  Every interior vertex has three children *except* that one.

Comment: These are certainly not star-like trees, because the [Wikipedia definition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starlike_tree) is violated by your last graph. There are more than one vertices with degree greater than $2$ in it.

Comment: @ShraddheyaShendre Ah good to know that option has been eliminated! :)

Comment: They look like the balls of radius $d$ about the identity, in the Cayley graph of the free group on 2 generators. The [wiki page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group) for the free group has this as its first image. You could equivalently consider these as balls of radius $d$ in the infinite 4-valent tree.